# Deriving the t-statistic for a difference-in-difference estimator

Tags: t-test, standard-error, difference-in-difference

For not-especially-pertinent reasons, I want to be able to manually calculate the equivalent of the difference-in-means *t*-test but for a scenario where instead I am testing whether a diff-in-diff is 0.

I am aware that this can be done by simply running a regression with an interaction term, where the interaction term will return the diff-in-diff estimator and its accompanying standard error and *t*-statistic. I am using that to tell whether I have the correct answer.

For the simple difference-in-means version, the *t*-statistic formula is well known and can be hand calculated based on:

$$t=\frac{\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}$$

I am trying to determine what the equivalent formulation is in a diff-in-diff setting. Specifically, it is not obvious how to formulate the standard error term in the denominator. It is tempting to say the answer should be:

$$t=\frac{(\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2})-(\bar{X_3}-\bar{X_4})}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}+\frac{\sigma_3^2}{n_3}+\frac{\sigma_4^2}{n_4}}}$$

It turns out this is the close-but-no-cigar answer, in that it matches the regression-output t-statistic if and only if the groups are equally-sized ($n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4$). However, if that assumption is not true, the answers very slightly differ between that equation and the regression output, suggesting that this is not quite the right approach to weighting the variances in the standard error term.

What is the appropriate formulation of the test statistic here? Does it exist in a tidy formulation, *i.e.*, without reference to the entire design matrix $X$ and the typical formulation of standard errors of coefficients in a regression based on $\sigma (X'X)^{-1}$?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you calculate the t-stat for any other regression coefficient?

Comment: Well you can do so based on the typical matrix algebra from OLS, as I mentioned, as $Var(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}. But that's not quite what I'm asking. I'm asking whether there is a solution equivalent to the standard difference-in-means one, where knowing the variances and observation counts is sufficient without actually using the full design matrix.

Comment: In particular, in the case of binary outcomes, knowing just the the average success rate and observation counts is sufficient to calculate the "difference in means" version of a t test so I'm wondering if there is an analogue for the diff-in-diff case where knowing just those is sufficient. Perhaps the answer is "no, no such form exists" but the fact that the one in my main answer exactly works for equally sized subgroups makes me thing it probably does.